# Find other column's value with their ids

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a simple MySQL database with two columns: 'text' and 'id' .

My goal would be to set a php variable to the 'text' column by only giving the id info.

For example:

Here would be the DataBase:

```
    ---text---id---      //columns
      test  /  1        //data
```

I want to give a variable '1' and the code to return a variable with 'test' .

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to assign the values to 2 different variables?

Comment: Yes, this would be my goal.

Comment: So according to your values in the questions you want `$test = 'test'` and `$id = 1` is it?

Comment: Yes, I need a variable $text to be equal to the text  column by only giving the id, which would be a $id variable.

Comment: Clarification !! SO what you are saying is you have assigned `$id = 1` in your code and need to get the value that has the id 1 right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Yeah !! what i meant was you want to get the value of text which has the id that you have assigned. Is that what you want to get?

Comment: Yes, I want to give $id='1' and set $text to 'test'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli_connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hexll");

$sqlquery= mysqli_query($mysqli_connect,"select text from mytable where id='1' ");

$row= mysqli_fetch_array($sqlquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo $row['text'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the task that is assigned for `id=1` in the following way using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
 $id = 1;

$sql = "SELECT task FROM your_db_table WHERE `id` = :id ";
$sql ->execute([ 'id' => $id]);
 $task= $sql;
```

And if you are using [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

```
 $id = 1;

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT task FROM your_db_table WHERE id =?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id); // 'i' specifies the variable type => 'integer'

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$text= $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: @Dharman I've showed how to query using PDO and I've showed him how to do the same thing without using pdo saying it's not recommended

Comment: @Dharman thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer.

Comment: What's the point of the loop?

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: The PDO example is still missing something. Please check the post linked as a duplicate of this one. It is explained there how to do it properly.